# how to count clicking on Interstitial? admob version 8 and above

Tags: admob, google-ads-api

Since willLeaveApplication has been removed on AdMob version 8, what can replace the `interstitialWillLeaveApplication` function?

Comment: hi, I just realized that my answer went unnoticed. was it useful?

Answer (score 0):

AdMob [reccomends](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration#presentation_ad_events) using `applicationWillResignActive` or `sceneWillResignActive`.

You can read more about those here:

- [applicationWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive?language=objc)
- [sceneWillResignActive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197919-scenewillresignactive?language=objc)